# Error Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS el consumir WS

Tags: vb.net, webservice, soap, ssl, tls

Estoy consumiendo un WS a través de VB.NET y recibo el error indicado más arriba.
Hay mucha información en la web referente al error

> Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS",

pero básicamente todo apunta a que hay que establecer el protocolo de seguridad antes de realizar la llamada HttpWebRequest
En mi código ya tengo implementado el protocolo de seguridad.. luce así. Estoy utilizando .NET Framework 4.7.2 en Windows Server 2012R2. Muchas gracias

```
Dim myString As String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soape .. </soapenv:Envelope>"
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 
Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.zetasoftware.com/z.apis.libra.apimpwsmovimientocliente")
req.KeepAlive = True
req.Timeout = 26000
req.Method = "POST"
req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate")
req.Host = "www.zetasoftware.com"
req.ContentLength = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString).Length
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "ZetaSoftwareaction/apis.libra.APIMPWSMOVIMIENTOCLIENTE.Execute")
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
req.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString).Count)
Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse
```

Comment: La opcion 3 de este enlace me sirvio. https://expertosenlinea.com.ar/windows-server-no-pudo-crear-un-error-de-canal-seguro-ssl-tls/